# Adding new records to a DataTable

Tags: sql, vb.net, ado.net

I am having trouble inserting new rows into a database with multiple tables. Currently I have my database connected to my Visual Basic project. What I have so far is this:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class MainForm

Private m_cn As New SqlConnection()
Private m_DA As SqlDataAdapter
Private m_CB As SqlCommandBuilder
Private m_DataTable As New DataTable
Private m_IntRowPosition As Integer = 0

    Private Sub MainForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        m_cn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename = C:\Users\pattanasio\Desktop\Visual Basic Projects\DPG Project Hours Database\Mestek Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"
        m_cn.Open()
        m_DA = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Employee_Table", m_cn)
        m_CB = New SqlCommandBuilder(m_DA)
        m_DA.Fill(m_DataTable)
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnInsertIntoDatabase_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnInsertIntoDatabase.Click
    Dim drNewRow As DataRow = m_DataTable.NewRow()

        For m_IntRowPosition = 0 To lstScannedNames.Items.Count()
             If m_DataTable.Rows.Count = 0 Then
                drNewRow("emp_id") = m_IntRowPosition + 1
                drNewRow("emp_name") = lstScannedNames.Items.Item(m_IntRowPosition)
                m_DataTable.Rows.Add(drNewRow)
                m_DA.Update(m_DataTable)
                m_IntRowPosition = m_DataTable.Rows.Count - 1
            End If
        Next m_IntRowPosition
    End Sub
End Class
```

When I run my program and click that button, I get an error on the `drNewRow("emp_name")` line saying that the column `emp_name` does not belong to the table. The full error says it is `An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll` I'm also wondering why the error isn't thrown on the line before where I reference the `emp_id` column. My guess is that I'm getting this error because my `DataTable` object does not know which data table in the database to reference. Also, it may be worth noting that `emp_id` is the primary key for 1 of my 5 tables and is also the foreign key in 3 other tables. I feel like I'm close but I've been stuck for a few hours. Sorry if my terminology isn't spot on, I'm quite new at this.

My Database looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDYoi.png).

Here is the pastebin link to my code: http://pastebin.com/UiYXEZMG

Ok, it is definitely worth noting that when I look through the `Autos` window to see the table my `drNewRow` is inserting into, and then use the text visualizer, it shows the 4 columns I originally had. 1 column for `emp_id` and 3 other columns for first, middle, and last name. However, in the database designer, I deleted 2 of the name columns and renamed the remaining one to `emp_name`, without touching `emp_id`. This is definitely the cause of my problem but I'm not sure how to fix it. **So in the database designer `.xsd` file it shows my table how I would like it to be. But in the `Autos` window it shows that it is using the old table.** Also if I wanted to work with a different table, would I just have to `SELECT` a different table in my `SqlDataAdapter`?

Comment: Indeed the code above doesn't initialize the Columns collection of the DataTable. Do you have some other code that tries to read the DataTable from the database (thus initializing the columns) or do you have some kind of manual initialization of the DataTable's columns?

Comment: @Steve I forgot to include my form's load event. I'm editing my question now

Comment: The code in the Load event fills the datatable with all data and schema of all columns from the database table Employee_Table. If there are no other changes that involves the m_DataTable variable then you don't have a column exactly spelled emp_name in the Employee_Table. A part from this the for loop seems to add only the first item of the _lstScannedNames_ and only if there are no row in the DataTAble. Is this really your intention?

Comment: @Steve Ahh yes, I need to remove that last statement where I set `m_IntRowPosition` to the last row to make the loop effective. I originally had this on its own and not in a loop so that is why I had it and it is not my intention to add only the first. I'll include a picture of the database designer in my question for clarification.

Comment: Well, something else should be at play here. There is no reason in the code above to blow on that line. If you are willing (or able) to share your code through some cloud disk service I will be glad to look at it,

Comment: what is `lstScannedNames`?  trying to work out what `lstScannedNames.Items.Item(m_IntRowPosition)` might work out to be

Comment: @Plutonix `lstScanedNames` is a listbox of names read from an excel file. @Steve I'll upload my full code to pastebin and link here once its up

Comment: So I fixed the problem by looking into the TableAdapter dialog box and seeing that, even though I changed the design of the table in the database designer, all that really did was un-include the last 2 columns from the `SELECT` statement and did not actually rename the column that I renamed. So now I am getting an error on the update line saying that it cannot INSERT NULL into one of the columns that I did not include in the `SELECT`. I'm not sure how to actually `ALTER` my table from visual studio since the designer doesn't do that. So I think I'll just recreate the table and reconnect it.